# How to loop files in a directory and export in DGV in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, directory, streamreader

I have my code:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstDir.Items.Count - 1  
         For Each File As String In Directory.GetFiles(lstDir.Items(i))
              Fname = File.ToString.Substring(File.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
              i = +1

              If File.Contains(".zip") Then
                  res = ""
                  For Each Str As Char In Fname
                      If IsNumeric(Str) Then
                         res = res & Str
                      End If
                  Next

                  For x As Integer = 0 To lstDir.Items.Count - 1
                      For Each newFile As String In Directory.GetFiles(lstDir.Items(x))
                          If newFile.Contains(res) Then
                             dgContents.Rows.Add(Fname)
                          End If
                       Next
                  Next

              End If

    Next
Next
```

suppose my directory contains these files:

```
abc123.pdf
def456.zip
ghi123.zip
jkl123.xml
mno456.pdf
pqr456.xml
```

I need to select just all **.zip files**, get the numbers in the zip filename, and loop again on the directory to search files with the same number from the zip then add it to datagrid. My problem is, my code displays output like this:

```
def456.zip
def456.zip
def456.zip
ghi123.zip
ghi123.zip
ghi123.zip
```

instead of

```
def456.zip
mno456.pdf
pqr456.xml 
ghi123.zip
abc123.pdf
jkl123.xml
```

please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you. I propose you to use next code.

This `Sub` is for looping through files with a `.zip` extension in a given path:

```
Imports System.IO

     Public Sub GetFilesFromDir(path As String)
                ' Make a reference to a directory.
                Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(path)
                ' Get a reference to each file in that directory.
                Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
                ' Display the names of the files.
                Dim file As FileInfo
                Dim fileName As String = ""
                For Each file In fiArr
                    If file.Extension = ".zip" Then
                        Console.WriteLine("------------- {0} -----------", file.Name)
                        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path & "\" & file.Name)
                        DisplayFilesByNumber(fiArr, fileName)
                    End If
                Next
     End Sub
```

The `DisplayFilesByNumber` is a `Sub` where the loop through files which contains a given string (in this case, the number in the `fileName`) is done.

```
Public Sub DisplayFilesByNumber(fiArr As FileInfo(), fileName As String)
        For Each fileByNumber In fiArr
            If fileByNumber.Name.Contains(GetNumbers(fileName)) Then
                Console.WriteLine(fileByNumber)
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

This `Sub` needs a simple function to get the number in the `fileName`.

```
Imports.Text.RegularExpressions

    Public Function GetNumbers(fileName As String) As String
            GetNumbers = Regex.Replace(fileName, "[^0-9]", String.Empty)
    End Function
```

This gives next output:

```
------------- def456.zip -----------
def456.zip
mno456.pdf
pqr456.xml
------------- ghi123.zip -----------
abc123.pdf
ghi123.zip
jkl123.xml
```

I hope I understood you correctly. I'm not storing values in a DGV but I'm sure you can cope with this.